# Extracting the json post parameter from aiohttp POST Request

Tags: python, aiohttp

currently I do something like this

```
app.router.add_route('POST', '/foo/{par}', foo_test)
```

How can I extract the body of the POST from request

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def foo_test(request):
    body = request.content.read() #returns a generator
```

My question is how to extract the body from the generator returned ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`body = yield from request.json()`